# Using TLS1.2 on Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, tls1.2, sslengine

Does anyone know a way to enable Android 4.0.4 to use TLS1.2 when making SSL connections?

I've read the answers to this question:
 - [Making SSLEngine use TLSv1.2 on Android (4.4.2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357863/making-sslengine-use-tlsv1-2-on-android-4-4-2)

However, Google Play Services are not available on the production Famoco NFC devices which are restricted to 4.0.4 due to the hardware.

Are there any libraries which help SSLEngine make the TLS1.2 connection?

Comment: Have you tried with adding spongycastle as a Provider? https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/

Comment: no - i'll have a go. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I think spongycastle will help in terms of ciphers, but not the protocol unfortunately.