# SSLException - Connection closed by peer on Android 4.x versions

Tags: android, ssl, android-4.4-kitkat

The issue is not occurring on higher OS versions. Is there a known problem on Android 4.x versions?
If yes, how can this issue be addressed? Should there be a change on the mobile app or on the backend side?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the full stack trace.

Comment: You need to provide much more information. Perhaps related to tls1.2 support -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357863/making-sslengine-use-tlsv1-2-on-android-4-4-2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I actually don't have the full stack trace. This is what's visible to me.

```
IOException:Connection closed by peer
EXCEPTION class: class javax.net.ssl.SSLException
EXCEPTION cause: null
EXCEPTION message: Connection closed by peer
RESPONSE: SSLException
```

The issue was due to TLSv1 being disabled on backend. 
Depending on the case there can be two approach to address this issue. 
1. Enable TLSv1 on backend server.
2. As suggested, [update the SSLEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357863/making-sslengine-use-tlsv1-2-on-android-4-4-2) to support higher TLS versions on mobile app.