# SSLHandshakeException while retrieving data from TheMovieDataBase using Retrofit+OkHttp in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, themoviedb-api

I am trying to **fetch list of movies** from TheMovieDatabase(TMDb)

**Get: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=${KEY}&page=1**

However, I am getting the following:

> HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by
>   peer

Following is the code I have already tried:

```
 if (okHttpClient == null) {

            ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS) //tried MODERN_TLS also
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                    .supportsTlsExtensions(true)                       
                    .cipherSuites(
                          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                          CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                          CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
                        )
                    .build();

            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
                    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .build();
        }

        if (retrofit == null)
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(APIUtils.BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
```

**Logs:**

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:318)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:282)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:167)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
>           at com.google.firebase.perf.network.FirebasePerfOkHttpClient.execute(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
>           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:42)
>           at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
>           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
>           at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
>           at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12030)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
>           at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:579)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
>           at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686625/disable-ssl-certificate-check-in-retrofit-library

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006416/sslexception-connection-closed-by-peer-on-android-4-x-versions/37021685#37021685

Comment: kdblue and Basi, tried both solutions getting the same error as above!