# VideoView how to enable TLS 1.2?

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, android-videoview

I am using VideoView to download and play video in my app. Server is communicating via tls 1.2 protocol and it is by default disabled on Android 4.4.2(KitKat) device. Since I am not using any special http client to download stream but android's VideoView component, I could not find a way to set ssl socket factory of the VideoView. Is there anyway to enable Tls 1.2 for VideoView http connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check below link:

[Making SSLEngine use TLSv1.2 on Android (4.4.2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357863/making-sslengine-use-tlsv1-2-on-android-4-4-2).

I have faced this issue for Image, Hope this solution help you in video view also.

```
try {
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            try {
                sslContext.init(null, null, null);
                SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
                engine.getEnabledCipherSuites();
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: VideoView just accepts a uri with videoView.setVideoURI() method and automatically downloads video. I am not sure if and how i can use this solution.

Comment: You can add in any of the your class just make sure before using video view. We have added this code in application class.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. Are you sure SSLEngine object is not passed to any method as parameter later in your code?

Comment: No, There is no such things to use it latter.

Comment: Ok, apparently the solution works, at least to download images. But I can't still download and play mp4 video on videoview, so I think the problem isn't related to tls version but videoview itself.