# SSLHandshakeException(Connection closed by peer) in Picasso while showing image from firebase strorage

Tags: android, firebase, ssl-certificate, peer

This question asked in SO several times in several manners, but no answer fill up my criteria.

I am trying to upload and download images from/to fire-base storage. To download Image I used Picasso. Some days ago my codes work fine and I am able to do my work (upload and download from/to firebase storage). But now I am only able to get the text from firebase database,   But not download or upload images to firebase storage, these tasks are stopped. I got Picasso error and my logcat says **SSLHandshakeException(Connection closed by peer)** . In stack overflow I have searched several answers, try them, but no luck.

One More thing, When I use a vpn connection it's work fine, then I can upload and download My Image fine. But, this is not the right way.

Any one can show me the way, How can I  upload and download images from/to firebase storage again ? I also have tried the below code, but no luck :

```
 private static void initializeSSLContext(Context mContext){
try {
    SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(mContext.getApplicationContext());
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Comment: Do you use a real device? If so, is it Samsung?

Comment: Yes, sir, I am using real device, And it is not Samsung, It is Walton Primo N3.

Comment: Or, Is there a way that I can fullfill the requirement of vpn?

Comment: Does this problem exist on different devices or emulator?

Comment: Yes, this problem also exists in my another app in another devices, though once they functioned properly.

Comment: could you please send a link with this error

Comment: Also your code is not the same as answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586324/4470269

Comment: I have tried these codes.but no luck. And my codes are firebase storage reference.